# Измерение время отклика в мс

Tags: python, datetime, время, python-3.9

Сейчас бот измеряет время ответа на запрос в секундах. Как перевести это в милисекунды?

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from time import time as tmm
tmm_before = int(dt.today().strftime('%S'))
requests.get("https://aminoapps.com/")
tmm_after = int(dt.today().strftime('%S'))
tmm_taken = tmm_after-tmm_before
print(f'Время отклика: {tmm_taken}')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998245/get-current-time-in-milliseconds-in-python

Comment: или тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/18426956/4804629

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему бы просто не умножить количество секунд на 1000

```
tmm_taken = (tmm_after-tmm_before) * 1000
```

Comment: @splash58 поправил, спасибо

Comment: Да, что-то вроде, но оно ведь все равно показывает именно точно, 1000, 2000. А мне нужно чтобы было что-то вроде 240 мс, 120 мс и т.д

Answer (score 1):

datetime дает результат с микросекундами, если система, на которой выполняется скрипт, поддерживает нужную точность

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

tmm_before = dt.today()
# sleep(3)  - измеряемый код
tmm_after = dt.today()
tmm_taken = (tmm_after-tmm_before)/timedelta(microseconds=1)/1000
print(f'Время отклика в мс: {tmm_taken}') # Время отклика в мс: 3014.093
```

Answer (score 1):

а если так попробовать:

```
from time import perf_counter, sleep

tmm_before = perf_counter()

sleep(0.12345)

tmm_after = perf_counter()
tmm_taken = (tmm_after-tmm_before)*1000
print(f'Время отклика: {int(tmm_taken)} mc')
'''
Время отклика: 135 mc
```